# How do I reverse words in a sentence in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am trying to reverse a string of words with this code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "please enter words to reverse:\n";
my $string = <STDIN>;
chomp $string;

my $rstring = reverse $string;

print "$rstring\n";
```

For example, when I enter `one two three`, the reverse words should be `three two one`. But I'm actually getting `eerht owt eno`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: @MladenB. it actually looks like an exercise from a programming book. But in this case the questions is more "please explain why my solution doesn't work" than "do this for me" -- and that's... not entirely on-topic the way it's phrased, but it shows the willingness to learn. And there is code, an explanation of the problem, what happens and what should happen. It's a complete [mcve] with a concrete problem. I think that's fair game, and if I can actually teach someone something, I will. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The computer doesn't know what a *word* is. When you call [`reverse`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) on a string, it will flip around all the characters. But `reverse` also allows you to flip around a list of things, which makes more sense in your context.

> In list context, returns a list value consisting of the elements of LIST in the opposite order. In scalar context, concatenates the elements of LIST and returns a string value with all characters in the opposite order.

You need to turn your string of *words* into a list of *words*, then turn that around, and then turn it back into a string.

If you look at your string, you will notice *words* are separated by empty space.

```
   V   V
one two three
```

You can [`split`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) the string into an array on these spaces. Note that `split` takes a pattern as the separator.

```
my @words = split / /, $string;
```

Now you have an array of *words*.

```
( 'one', 'two', 'three' )
```

When you `reverse` that, it will do it to the elements, not each string inside them, so you get

```
my @words = reverse split / /, $string;
# ( 'three', 'two', 'one' )
```

Finally, if you want to put the spaces back in, use the opposite of `split` to [`join`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) the list into a string again.

```
print join ' ', reverse split / /, $string;
# three two one
```

Comment: pedantically, that should be `split / /, $string, -1` so trailing spaces are preserved (moved to the beginning) the way leading spaces are (moved to the end)